# Inherit decorator defined in parent class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

Rather than try to explain verbosely, this code snippet should do it.

```
def decorator(function):
    return lambda self: function(self) + 1

# imported from library
class A(object):
    # override
    def method_1(self):
        pass

    # override
    def method_2(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def method_1(self):
        return 1

class C(B):
    @decorator
    def method_2(self):
        return 1

class D(B):
    @decorator
    def method_2(self):
        return 2

print C().method_1() # 1
print C().method_2() # 2
print D().method_2() # 3
```

This works well, but as `decorator` is only used on `method_2`, maybe it should be pulled in.

```
class B(A):
    def method_1(self):
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def decorator(function):
        return lambda self: function(self) + 1

class C(B):
    @B.decorator
    def method_2(self):
        return 1
```

This works, but it's not clear to me if this is actually better. In particular whether Python treats `B.decorator` like an *external* function which just happens to be defined on `B`, or if `C` inheriting from `B` makes this more efficient.

What I actually want is some way to define the decorator on `B` and use it on `C` like this.

```
class C(B):
    @self.decorator
    def method_2(self):
        return 1
```

This doesn't work. Is there a better alternative to either perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any particular reason to move the decorator into the class. It's perfectly normal to have helper stuff outside of the class in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that there is no reason to move the decoration definition to inside the class, as pointed in the comments, there goes some clarifications:

when you do use the `@staticmethod` decorator on your decorator definition, you will have the exact same behavior as if it was defined outside any class body.

If you do use `@classmethod` instead, as in

```
 class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def decorator(cls, function):
        return lambda self: function(self) + 1
```

The difference is that the decorator is passed the class it is defined in, as an object as the first parameter. This could be of some use, or not - note that the decorated method itself will still be a regular instance method - unless you make use of `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorators inside the decorator body itself, changing the wrapper function it returns.

As for efficient: the most "efficient" thing will be to just leave teh decorator outside any class body - the difference for a "@staticmethod" defiend decorator will be minimal - probably impossible to measure at all, but should involve two or three less attribute accesses on class creation (which won't usually be inside a critical loop in the application) - so, no, there is no difference there.

Now, it is not what you are asking, but someone could come here looking for how to automatically re-apply a decorator in a method in a superclass when overreding this method in a sub-class: 
That is not easy to do, but should be possible with specially prepared decorators (which will anotate themselves on the wrapped method)